# Why was my prophets of mercy question migrated yet my guitar question is on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, closed-questions, off-topic, migration

[Are questions on jokes or about fictional events on topic?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7003/are-questions-on-jokes-or-about-fictional-events-on-topic)

[What's up with churches and guitars in this joke from The Big Bang Theory?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/55532/whats-up-with-churches-and-guitars-in-this-joke-from-the-big-bang-theory)

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/111915/what-were-the-prophets-of-mercy

Comment: That I deleted this (thinking that it was mostly a duplicate of your other question) and then thought again and undeleted it a minute later is not important. I'm not hiding the fact I did it, it's just not important. Don't add irrelevant information like that to your question.

Answer (score 3):

Your new question was migrated because it has absolutely nothing to do with Christianity. I suggest you not ask questions with no clear relevance to Christianity here again.

Comment: the quote 'the prophets of mercy beat the priestly cult and its emphasis on ritual purity' is in fact related to the bible. idk if the bible is related to CHRISTIANITY though. sheldon was talking about bible camp.

Comment: 'I suggest you not ask questions here like that again.' --> may i ask more questions like this? https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/55532/whats-up-with-churches-and-guitars-in-this-joke-from-the-big-bang-theory

Comment: How do you know it's about the Bible? And how are ***we*** meant to know it's about the Bible?

Comment: LOL my question was migrated because it was unclear? The context is sheldon said that to someone at bible camp. look it appears there's no such thing as 'prophets of mercy' i think this is similar to asking maths se or computer science se what 'bergofsky principle' means. it's made up. based on mathematical or computer science expertise, you know there's no such thing as 'bergofsky principle'. similarly based on christianity expertise, you know there's no such thing as 'prophets of mercy'

Comment: Read your question again. You never mention Bible Camp. Even if you did, that doesn't mean that the quote has anything to do with the Bible. And if you know there are no prophets of mercy, then you already know it doesn't have anything to do with Christianity, so why did you ask it here?

Comment: I can't tell you whether questions you haven't posted will be off topic or not before I see them. Use your best judgement.

Comment: curiousdannii♦ because i didn't know for sure there's no such thing as prophets of mercy BECAUSE I'M NOT an expert :|

Comment: ok BUT my tbbt question IS on-topic for the site right?

Comment: That's for the community to decide. It's definitely not a good exemplar of a question for this site, it's at best barely on topic, as we said before.

Comment: curiousdannii♦ so why don't you migrate the question? or you don't think the question should be migrated?

Comment: The question is too old to migrate now. If it was a new question I probably would migrate it, it's certainly much more appropriate at Movies & TV.

Comment: curiousdannii♦ so it was a MISTAKE that it wasn't migrated? why don't you at least close if you can't migrate? how come the post has not been closed after all these votes and views?

Comment: I wasn't a mod three years ago. I won't close it unilaterally because as I've already explained so many times before I think it is just barely not off topic. But if people do start voting to close it then they might persuade me to vote to close it too. You can try to persuade me that it is on topic, that would certainly be far more productive than all of these Meta arguments you're having with me.

Comment: curiousdannii♦ wait persuade you that which question is on topic? the TBBT one? or the young sheldon one?

Comment: Frankly, in its migrated form the question also falls flat of the primary rule of migration, though.

Answer (score 3):

That *Young Sheldon* question had no clear connection to Christianity, lots and lots of real and imagined religions have a notion of a priesthood.  Judaism, Rush songs, Japenese RPG's, they're not about Christianity and that's where the clear line ought to be drawn.